# Wordpress Understrap display posts on a page

Tags: php, wordpress, bootstrap-4

I'm learning how to use wordpress API. I'm a newbie with this framework, so I've decided to install Understrap to use the Bootstrap 4 framework and create a simple portfolio website. After googling a bit, I've started experimenting with the code, but there are many aspects of this wordpress theme that are unclear to me. I want to display some posts on a page and style how they will appear using the bootstrap classes markup. Is there any valid tutorial about or anyone can suggest to me the correct modifications I need to make to the template theme files?

I've tried to create a page named postpage.php with this code inside, but it will not be recognized from wordpress as a template model for a page.
CODE:

```
<?php

$args = array(
'posts_per_page' => 6,
'offset' => 0,
'category' => 'portfolio',
'category_name' => '',
'orderby' => 'date',
'order' => 'DESC',
'include' => '', 'exclude' => '',
'meta_key' => '',
'meta_value' => '',
'post_type' => 'post', 'post_mime_type' => '',
'post_parent' => '',
'author' => '',
'post_status' => 'publish',
'suppress_filters' => true
);

$myposts = get_posts( $args );

foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
<li>
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
</li>
<?php
endforeach;
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to specify that this is a page template by adding the following code to the top of your file:

```
<?php /* Template Name: Example Template */ ?>
```

Then it will show up in your page template dropdown. More info about [page templates here](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/).

In order to add Boostrap classes, you need to wrap the `foreach` statement in the Bootstrap containers and then change the `ul` to bootstrap columns:

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <?php foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata($post ); ?>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
    </div>
    <?php endforeach; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok, thank you I will try the code and let you know. I was giving a look to the various template pages of understrap, I've noticed that It will use a `col-md-12` to wrap all the site contents. If I want to add multiple rows, I need to duplicate the loop or something similar to show the contents right?

Comment: You would need to add a counter to the `foreach` statement and then use the count to determine when to add a row closing div and a new opening row div, which is a bit more advanced. The nice thing about Bootstrap is that it's not always necessary to separate into rows. For instance, if you had 12 posts and you used 4 column divs, it would automatically put the posts into 4 rows even if they're all inside the same "row."

Comment: I will base my page on the blank template provided by understrap, It will be more customizable for me that are a wordpress newbie. Can you confirm that from this code I need only to add the correct bs4 markup?
`<?php
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
 exit; // Exit if accessed directly.
}
get_header();
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
 get_template_part( 'loop-templates/content', 'empty' );
endwhile;
get_footer();`

Comment: I don't have any experience with Understrap, sorry.

Comment: Don't worry, your answer helped me a lot, now I've the page template working fine and I need only to add the bootstrap custom markup. thank you.

Comment: You're quite welcome, if you have any further questions, please create a new question and link it here I will do my best to assist you.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use custom layout then you need to make a custom template and there you will add a page for using your custom templet. your custom template code will like this

```html
<?php
/* Template Name: Your custom templete */
get_header();
?><?php $the_query = new WP_Query(array(
'category_name'    => 'popular',
'posts_per_page' => '6',
'order' => 'DESC', // Show only the published posts
));?>
<?php if( $the_query->have_posts() ): ?>
<?php while( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();?>
<div class="story-info">
<a class="category-name arts texunset" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
<span class="daycolor" style="background:<?php the_field('colorpost'); ?>;">&nbsp;</span>
<span>
<?php the_title(); ?>
</span>
</a>
<div class="date">
<?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?> &nbsp;|&nbsp;
<i class="fa fa-signal"></i>
</div>
</div>
<hr>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php get_footer();?>
```